# Jtable with a custom layout is flickering when the user scrolls it

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtable, flicker

I have done a custom table that extends JTable. My custom table differs in the layout where it has a JPanel with a button at the bottom of the table. *The panel shall always be at the bottom of the **visible part** of the table regardless of the scroll position.*

It almost works as I want it except **that it is flickering when I scroll the table**. And that **some rows are behind the panel**.

Is it possible to make the code better in someway, to get rid of the flickering and make it so no rows will be behind the panel?

Here is a working example of my custom table:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import java.awt.*;

class TableDemo {
    public static void main(String[]args){
          new TableDemo();
    }

    public TableDemo() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        CustomTable table = new CustomTable();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        table.initChangeListener();
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class CustomTable extends JTable {
        private TableLayout layout = new TableLayout();
        public CustomTable() {
            super(100,10);
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
            panel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            panel.add(new JButton("Press me!"));
            this.add(panel);
            this.setLayout(layout);
        }

        public void initChangeListener() {
            if(this.getParent() != null) {
                if(this.getParent() instanceof JViewport) {
                    JViewport viewport = (JViewport)this.getParent();
                    viewport.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                            if(CustomTable.this.getLayout() instanceof TableLayout) {
                                CustomTable.this.getLayout().layoutContainer(CustomTable.this);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class TableLayout implements LayoutManager {

        @Override
        public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {}

        @Override
        public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {}

        @Override
        public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            return parent.getPreferredSize();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            return parent.getMinimumSize();
        }


        @Override
        public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
            CustomTable table = (CustomTable)parent;
            JViewport vp = (JViewport)table.getParent();
            Point p = vp.getViewPosition();
            Rectangle rectangle = vp.getVisibleRect();

            for(Component c : parent.getComponents()) {
                if(c instanceof JPanel) {
                    c.setBounds(0,  p.y + (int)rectangle.getHeight() - 40, (int)rectangle.getWidth(), (int)rectangle.getHeight());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. let JViewport for whales, apply LayoutManager to its parent, to the JScrollPane, 2. JTable can't returns reasonable PreferredSize, override etPreferredScrollableViewportSize for JScrollPanes childs, 3. setBounds are wrong way, can to kill good intentions totally

Comment: Why not use a separate component?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using custom layout ? Is there any special purpose of it ? If not I think I have an alternate suggession

You can create a new component by extending JPanel (or JComponent) instead of extending JTable and you can add JTable with scroll pane and Button panel to that container. Please see the code below.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

class TableDemo {
public static void main(String[]args){
      new TableDemo();
}

public TableDemo() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    CustomTable table = new CustomTable();
    frame.add(table);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


class CustomTable extends JPanel
{

    JTable table;
    JPanel buttonPanel;

    public CustomTable() {
        super();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        table=new JTable(100,10);
        JScrollPane scrollPane=new JScrollPane(table);
        buttonPanel=new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Press Me"));

        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
}
```